# "data" field not populated in axios response from express server

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, get, axios

I am trying to access data from a nodejs server using Express on the server and Axios on the backend.

This is the endpoing I am trying to reach: http://gentle-bastion-49098.herokuapp.com/api/filters

As you can see it actually returns data when you navigate to it. But when I try to access it using the following code:

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://gentle-bastion-49098.herokuapp.com/api'

function getFilterData () {
  const url = `${BASE_URL}/filters`
  return axios.get(url)
}
```

```
getFilterData()
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log('filter', response)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          alert('Could not get filters ' + err.message.toString())
        })
```

I get this response with the "data" field being unpopulated where I'm expecting it to contain the  JSON you see in the URL.

```
{
    "data": "",
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "headers": {},
    "config": {
        "url": "http://gentle-bastion-49098.herokuapp.com/api/filters",
        "method": "get",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        },
        "transformRequest": [null],
        "transformResponse": [null],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1
    },
    "request": {}
}
```

Here is the back end code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const async = require('async');
const request = require('request');
const http = require('http');
const EventSource = require('eventsource');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

app.get('/api/filters', function(req, res) {
    let filtersResponse = {
        "ID": "CONV_DATA@IVA",
        "ApplicationName": "InterationsView",
        "Type": "FILT_DETAIL",
        "filters": [{
                "Name": "ChannelType",
                "Values": uniqueFilters.ChannelType,
            },
            {
                "Name": "sessionType",
                "Values": uniqueFilters.sessionType,
            },
            {
                "Name": "Direction",
                "Values": uniqueFilters.Direction,
            },
            {
                "Name": "Status",
                "Values": uniqueFilters.Status,
            },
            {
                "Name": "statusReason",
                "Values": uniqueFilters.statusReason,
            },
        ],
        "minDuration": uniqueFilters.minDuration,
        "maxDuration": uniqueFilters.maxDuration,
        "minData": "2019-08-29T22:28:47.029UTC",
        "maxDate": "2019-08-29T22:28:49.578UTC"
    };

    // Respond with filters
    res.json(filtersResponse);
});
```

Any ideas as to why the data field is unpopulated even though when accessed through browser or postman it returns the desired data? Is it a problem with the back end or the way the request is being made? Thanks.
I have also enabled cross-orgin resource sharing on my browser. Not doing so results in an error

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear whether you are not getting axios response or response from your node server. If you have problem in getting axios response here is the code.

I have used `request` npm for making a get request.

```
const request = require('request');

apiUrl = "http://gentle-bastion-49098.herokuapp.com/api/filters"

request.get(
    {
        url: apiUrl,
        json: true
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error Occurred :", error);
        }
        console.log("Response Data :", body)

    }
);
```

The above code will give you response as :

```
{
   "ID":"CONV_DATA@IVA",
   "ApplicationName":"InterationsView",
   "Type":"FILT_DETAIL",
   "filters":[
      {
         "Name":"ChannelType",
         "Values":[
            "Phone",
            "Web-Chat",
            "Google-Assistant"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name":"sessionType",
         "Values":[
            "nlu-voice",
            "nlu-text"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name":"Direction",
         "Values":[
            "In"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name":"Status",
         "Values":[
            "Complete",
            "Started"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name":"statusReason",
         "Values":[
            "END"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "minDuration":9.7,
   "maxDuration":154.2,
   "minData":"2019-08-29T22:28:47.029UTC",
   "maxDate":"2019-08-29T22:28:49.578UTC"
}
```

which is same as what you get in browser when you visit the link  http://gentle-bastion-49098.herokuapp.com/api/filters

If you are using axios the code will be :

```
const axios = require('axios');

apiUrl = "http://gentle-bastion-49098.herokuapp.com/api/filters"

axios.get(apiUrl)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Response Data :", response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error Occurred :", error);
    })
```

and it will give same response as above.

Even your written code is giving response :

[image: Response Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try with these changes:

```
 getFilterData().then(response => {
          console.log('filter', response.data)
 })
  .catch(err => {
          alert('Could not get filters ' + err.message.toString())
 })
```

In your server code, send the response back to client using `res.send()` as shown below:

```
 app.get('/api/filters', function(req, res) {
    let filtersResponse = {
        "ID": "CONV_DATA@IVA",
        "ApplicationName": "InterationsView",
        "Type": "FILT_DETAIL",
        "filters": [{
                "Name": "ChannelType",
                "Values": uniqueFilters.ChannelType,
            },
            {
                "Name": "sessionType",
                "Values": uniqueFilters.sessionType,
            },
            {
                "Name": "Direction",
                "Values": uniqueFilters.Direction,
            },
            {
                "Name": "Status",
                "Values": uniqueFilters.Status,
            },
            {
                "Name": "statusReason",
                "Values": uniqueFilters.statusReason,
            },
        ],
        "minDuration": uniqueFilters.minDuration,
        "maxDuration": uniqueFilters.maxDuration,
        "minData": "2019-08-29T22:28:47.029UTC",
        "maxDate": "2019-08-29T22:28:49.578UTC"
    };

    // Respond with filters
 res.send(
    filtersResponse
  )
 });
```